# How to insert the data from the form to the database and get the last inserted ID / create uniqueID as the user's Session in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am trying to submit a form to the database and want to create a session. A session that can be used is either the Last Inserted ID or create uniqueID as a session. The issue that what I am facing is, whenever I am trying to refresh the page, my sessionID keeps incrementing because new record was inserted in the database.

**View: Welcome_Message.php**

```
    <form method="POST" action="GetQuotes/quote" id="ink-form" name="ink-form">
    <ul class="inkappform inkbookform">
    <li class="textheading ink-ff-row"><h2><span class="msg_text">To get a quote, select your vehicle type</span></h2></li>
    <li class = "textfname ink-ff-row"><input type = "text" name = "bk_name" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "First name" required = "" autocomplete="off" /></li>
    <li class = "textlname ink-ff-row"><input type = "text" id = "bk_lname" name = "bk_lname" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Last name" autocomplete="off" /></li>
    <li class = "textaptemail ink-ff-row"><input type = "email" name = "bk_email" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Email" required = "" autocomplete="off" /></li>
    <li class = "textaptemail ink-ff-row"><input type = "text" name = "bk_contact" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Contact number" required = "" autocomplete="off" /></li>
    <li class = "textaptphone ink-ff-row"><input type = "text" name = "pick_add" list="pu_postcode" id = "pick_add" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Type Pickup Posctcode" required = "" autocomplete="off" />
    <datalist id="pu_postcode">
    <option value=“001”>001 </option> 
    <option value=“002”>002 </option> 
    <option value=“003”>003 </option> 
    <option value=“004”>004 </option> 
    </datalist> </li>
    <li class = "textaptphone ink-ff-row"><input type = "text" name = "drop_add" list="do_postcode" id = "drop_add" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Type Dropoff Postcode" required = "" autocomplete="off" />
    <datalist id="do_postcode">
    <option value=“001”>001 </option> 
    <option value=“002”>002 </option> 
    <option value=“003”>003 </option> 
    <option value=“004”>004 </option> 
    </datalist> </li>
    <li class = "textaptphone ink-ff-row">
    <input type = "text" name = "car_list" list="car_dalalist" id = "car_list" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Type of Car" required = "" autocomplete="off" />
    <datalist id="car_dalalist">
    <option value=“BMW”>BMW </option> 
    <option value=“Merc”>Merc </option> 
    <option value=“Honda”>Honda </option> 
    <option value=“Toyota”>Toyota </option> 
    </datalist> </li>
    <li class = "textaptphone ink-ff-row">
    <input type = "text" name = "car_models" list="car_model_dalalist" id = "car_models" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Car Model" required = "" autocomplete="off" />
     <datalist id="car_model_dalalist">
    // Car Models list populates
    </datalist> </li>
    <li class = "textaptphone ink-ff-row">
    <input type = "text" name = "car_man_year" list="car_year_dalalist" id = "car_man_year" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Manufacturing Year" required = "" autocomplete="off" />
    <datalist id="car_year_dalalist">
    //Manufacturing list populates
    </datalist>  </li>
    <li class = "select_item ink-ff-row">
    <input type = "text" name = "bodytypeselect" list="car_bodytype_dalalist" id = "bodytypeselect" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Body Type" required = "" autocomplete="off" />
    <datalist id="car_bodytype_dalalist">
    <select  id="cbody"></select>
    </datalist>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" name="estimate" id="submit" class='ink-submit inkrequired' value="Estimate Quote"/>  
    </ul>
    </form>
```

After filling the data, the form call **GetQuotes/quote**

```
    public function quote()
 {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

         $first_name = $this->input->post('bk_name');
         $last_name = $this->input->post('bk_lname');
         $email = $this->input->post('bk_email');
         $contact = $this->input->post('bk_contact');
         $p_address = $this->input->post('pick_add');
         $d_address = $this->input->post('drop_add');
         $carList = $this->input->post('car_list');
         $carModel = $this->input->post('car_models');
         $carbodytype = $this->input->post('bodytypeselect');
         $manYear = $this->input->post('car_man_year');
         $sessionID = $this->input->post('SessID');
         $btn = $this->input->post('estimate');  


         $this->session->set_flashdata('fname', $first_name);
         $this->session->set_flashdata('lname', $last_name);
         $this->session->set_flashdata('pick_pc', $p_address);
         $this->session->set_flashdata('drop_pc', $d_address);

         $this->session->set_flashdata('carMake', $carList);
         $this->session->set_flashdata('carModel', $carModel);
         $this->session->set_flashdata('carSize', $carbodytype);
         $this->session->set_flashdata('ManYear', $manYear);
         if ($first_name && $last_name && $p_address && $d_address && $carList) {
                // Loading model


                 $data = array('First_Name'=> $first_name, 'Last_Name' => $last_name, 'Email' => $email, 'Phone' => $contact, 'Origin' => $p_address, 'Destination' => $d_address, 'CarMake' => $carList, 
                 'CarModel' => $carModel, 'ManYear' => $manYear, 'CarType' => $carbodytype, 'SessionID' => $sessionID  );

                $sID = $this->PostModel->insertToQuoteForm($data);
                }
        }



          $data = $this->getNewQuoteNumber();
          $this->load->view('insertNewQuote', $data);


  }


   function getNewQuoteNumber () {
         $data = array();
         $this->session->keep_flashdata('QuoteNo');
         $qNo = $this->session->flashdata('QuoteNo');

         $first_name = $this->session->flashdata('fname');
         $last_name = $this->session->flashdata('lname');
         $p_address = $this->session->flashdata('pick_pc');
         $d_address = $this->session->flashdata('drop_pc');

         $carList = $this->session->flashdata('carMake');
         $carModel = $this->session->flashdata('carModel');
         $carbodytype = $this->session->flashdata('carSize');
         $manYear = $this->session->flashdata('ManYear');


         echo 'qNo is:: '. $qNo ;
         echo '<br> Fname is:: '. $first_name ;
         echo '<br> CarType is:: '. $carbodytype ;


         $data['quotes_fetched'] = $this->PostModel->getQuotes();  // load the view file , we are passing $data array to view file
         $data['withgoods_quotes_fetched'] = $this->PostModel->withGoodsGetQuotes();
         $data['rowstotal'] = count($data['quotes_fetched']);
         //$this->PostModel->insertToQuoteForm();
         $this->load->view('page_header');

         $this->load->view('page_menu'); 
         $this->load->view('QueryHandler/Quote', $data);
         $this->load->view('page_footer'); 

  }
```

And Model:- **PostModel.php**

```
function insertToQuoteForm($data) {

                $this->db->insert('Quote_Form', $data);
                // Return the id of inserted row
                return $idOfInsertedData = $this->db->insert_id();




                 }
```

When the form is submitted, it inserts the data in the database as well as Fetches the data to give the estimated quote calculated back to the users. If the user refreshes the page, I want to either stop inserting the data in the database or use a session to display.

Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a predefined function in PHP called "last insert id". It can be used in PDO and mysqli. Inside your php model:

```
 function insertToQuoteForm($data) {
      if($this->db->insert('Quote_Form', $data)){ //check if successful
          return $this->db->lastInsertId(); //return the ID of the last insert
      }
 }
```

And inside your quote.php, you need to put this:

```
 $sID = $this->PostModel->insertToQuoteForm($data);
 $_SESSION['lastInserted'] = $sID;
```

Comment: Thanks @JJ Laboja, I am able to get the last inserted ID and trying to make this ID as a flashdata. But when I refresh the page, it again generates new ID and I lose the last ID which was registered as flashdata. I also tried userdata and same issue.

Comment: @SarahMalik base on your code, it always generates new ID everytime you insert data to Quote_Form. Technically, it's not an issue. If you found it an issue, you must change the logic of your program in the way how it should be. I'm glad I helped for some way.

Answer (score 1):

In the model check first, if new record then inserts directly else return the old id.
Something similar to this :

```
$temp = $data;
unset($temp['SessionID']);
$this->db->where($temp);
$query = $this->db->get('Quote_Form');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $result = $query->result();
    return $idOfInsertedData = $result->id;
}
$this->db->insert('Quote_Form', $data);
return $idOfInsertedData = $this->db->insert_id();
```